# Using Java deleting files with walkFileTree and SimpleFileVisitor - FileSystemException

Tags: java, java-8, nio

When I'm trying to delete files very few files in the same directory get access issues as below in error logs. There are 8 files in that directory but only 2 files are not able to delete and throwing the below error. Find the below code sample, anything I am missing?

Code Sample:-

```
public class ExtraFileCleaner implements AutoCloseable {
    
    private static final ExecutorService EXE_SERVICE = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    
    protected ExtraFileCleaner() {
        //TODO
    }

    public void deleteFilePath(final Path path) {
        if (path != null && Files.exists(path) && Files.isWritable(path)) {
            EXE_SERVICE.submit(() -> {
                try {
                    Files.walkFileTree(path, new DeletingFileVistor());
                } catch (NoSuchFileException e) {
                    log.debug("Path does not exist: " + path);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    log.warn("Delete failed: {} ", e.getMessage());
                }
            });
        }
    }  
     
       

    @Override
    public void close() throws InterruptedException {
        DELETE_SERVICE.shutdown();
        if (!EXE_SERVICE.awaitTermination(1 * 60 * 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
            EXE_SERVICE.shutdownNow();
        }       
    }
    
    public static class DeletingFileVistor extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path> {
                                
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path path, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
            log.info("visitFile: {}", path.toString());
            return visit(path);
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path path, IOException exc) throws IOException {
            log.info("POSTvisitFile: {}", path.toString());
            return visit(path);
        }
        
        private FileVisitResult visit(Path path) {
            FibonacciDelay delay = new FibonacciDelay();
            for (int attempt = 0; attempt < delay.getMaxAttempts(); attempt++) {
                try {
                    Files.deleteIfExists(path);
                    log.info("Deleted: {}", path.toString());
                    break;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    String msg = e.getMessage();
                    
                    log.info("exception-2 {}", msg);
                    if (e instanceof FileSystemException && msg != null && msg.contains("The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process")) {
                        log.debug("File is in use: {}", path.toString());
                    } else {
                        log.debug("{}: {}", new Object[]{e.getClass().getSimpleName(), e.getMessage()});
                    }
                    delay.doWait(attempt);   
                }
                if (attempt == delay.getMaxAttempts() - 1) {
                    log.warn("Delete aborted: {}", path.toString());
                }
            }
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    }
    
   
}
```

I getting this below error :

```
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\ProgramData\XYZ\FileManager\local\work\2b5f439e-cb80-4be9-a4ff-c7c796ba\test.1.0.jar: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:92)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:274)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.deleteIfExists(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:110)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists(Files.java:1181)
    at com.zyz.abc.file.WorkDirectoryCleaner$DeletingFileVistor.visit(WorkDirectoryCleaner.java:110)
    at com.zyz.abc.file.WorkDirectoryCleaner$DeletingFileVistor.visitFile(WorkDirectoryCleaner.java:98)
    at com.zyz.abc.file.WorkDirectoryCleaner$DeletingFileVistor.visitFile(WorkDirectoryCleaner.java:94)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2725)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2797)
    at com.zyz.abc.file.WorkDirectoryCleaner.lambda$deletePath$0(WorkDirectoryCleaner.java:40)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Comment: Some process is accessing the file you want to delete and Windows prevents the deletion. You need to [find out which process is locking a file or folder in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/117902/find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows) and either terminate that process or make it release the file in some other way. (Perhaps you have opened the .jar file in some explorer or archive manager or it is used by some JVM instance?)

Comment: This is happening even in Linux machine also.

Comment: What's in C:\ProgramData\XYZ\FileManager\local\work\2b5f439e-cb80-4be9-a4ff-c7c796ba\test.1.0.jar?